# pip - process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: python, pip

3rd week learning python. I am trying to pip install pyperclip. When I run this in the command prompt I am getting a permission error -

**PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\Users\my_user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpybqp3z0q'**

I can go into the folder Temp and delete tmpybqp3z0q, but when I run the command prompt again it will create a new file in this folder and give me the same error, now referencing the newly created file.

Comment: Are you running some other process like Spyder or Pycharm IDE which also manage pip packages?

Comment: I have bee using pyrcharm IDE but I don't know if they are managing pip packages

Comment: PyCharm can install dependencies for you, and is probably what is locking pip from external access - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Answer (score 1):

Run your terminal as an administrator and run

`python -m pip install –upgrade pip`

then run

`pip install --user pyperclip`

Comment: But `--user` in the admin terminal would install for "the admin" user. Pip shouldn't need admin permissions.

Comment: I tried to do --user pyperclip and it still gave me the same response